# Accesing an array element in solidity struct from Python

Tags: python, solidity

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I am trying to access a position in an array within a solidity structure from Python:

```
struct Data {
      bool exists;
      string DocumentURI;
      AGREEMENT_STATE state;
      address[] holdersArray;
      uint holdersCounter;
      
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

I know that for accesing a given element of an structure, I should refer to its position with brackets (in this case, [3]), but, how can I access a position of an array inside an structure? I hace tried 3, but it throws an error ('wei' object is not callable)

Comment: It is hard to answer, because this is not valid Python code as far as I know. You should first think about how to transfer this struct to a Python data type (e.g. dict, namedtuple, dataclass, ...) and then thinking about accessing it. The access to the data structure depends on the data type, then.

Comment: Thank you! I found a turnaround for this (I am a newbie as Python programmer). I have created a simple function in Solidity for reading this structure. Thank you anyway!